# Websocket post request to NODE server and not get response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, axios

I am trying to build a node server which as a middleman for my website. Several libraries are used.

1. `Axios`, I use `axios` to post requests to `API` and get the data from database
2. `Socket.io`, I use `socket.io` for recording who login and broadcast the message to every user if needed.
3. `Express`, I use it to host my `React` web app.

For the web app, I use `componentDidMount` and `Axios` to fetch data when the page is started and pressed the login button respectively. However, not every time the node server response, I will say its freezed. Sometime I press "Esc", and it will response the message back. How can I make sure it returns every time? Thanks a lot!

Partial Code from node js:

```
server.js

#for access DB
const DBhttp = require('http');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('common', { stream: serverLogStream}));
app.use('/api/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/api', router);
let DBserver;
DBserver = DBhttp.createServer(app)

#Express for host app
var AppServer;
var http;
var webApp = express();
webApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
webApp.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
AppServer= http.createServer(options, webApp);

#socket.io commumicate between app
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
var io = socketIO.listen(server);
var clients = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
#do the communication
}
```

React

```
react_index.js
initializeSession(this.state.loginName); #connect socket
this.setState({isLogin:true});

axios.post(SERVER_NAME + 'api/afterLogin')
.then((res) => {
   this.setState({
       full_name : res.data,
   })
   return Promise.resolve('Success')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more client right on your server to connect it to the same channel and see all the responses.
You can write the simple index.html with alike code:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }
        var socket = io.connect({'YOUR PATH TO SOCKET SERVER'});
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('socket.on connect');
        });
      socket.on('message', function (msg) {
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(JSON.stringify(msg)));
      });
      socket.on('update', function (msg) {
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(JSON.stringify(msg)));
      });
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('socket.on disconnect');
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

On editing it as you need, you can enable it like this:

```
app.get('/socketIo', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Now you can see all the responses, which your server sends to the address `{YOUR PATH TO SERVER}/socketIo`
Also it would be beneficial to add `console.log`, to get the information about the clients

```
io.clients((error, clients) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('clients ', clients);
});
```

This way you'll know whether your client is working